# Dynamic T-SQL error when converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: t-sql

I am getting the following error when I execute the below dynamic stored proc with

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[proc_InsertEventDetails]
        @EventID = 10254,
        @EventDetType = 65,
        @EventDetValue = 2,
        @EventDetPriority = 0,
        @CreatedBy = '4A47FE71-FC09-4E05-89E9-F68942BB9634'
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_InsertEventDetails, Line 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I haved looked all over stackoverflow help is much appreatiated. thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_InsertEventDetails]
(
     @EventID bigint    
    ,@EventDetType int
    ,@EventDetValue int
    ,@EventDetPriority int
    ,@CreatedBy uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN

     DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @SQL = 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT EventID FROM Events.[dbo].[EventDetail] 
            WHERE EventID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @EventID) + '
            AND EventDetType = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@EventDetType, 0)) + '  
            AND EventDetValue = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@EventDetValue, 0)) + ' 
            AND EventDetActive = 1) 
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO xxx.[dbo]..[EventDetail]
                    (
                    [EventID]
                    ,[EventDetType]
                    ,[EventDetValue]
                    ,[EventDetPriority]
                    ,[EventDetActive]
                    ,[EventDetSort]
                    ,[CreatedBy]
                    ,[CreatedDateTime]
                    ,[UpdatedBy]
                    ,[UpdatedDateTime]
                    )
                VALUES
                    (           
                     ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @EventID) + '
                    ,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@EventDetType, 0)) + '
                    ,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@EventDetValue, 0)) + '
                    ,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@EventDetPriority, 0)) + '
                    ,1
                    ,0
                    ,''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), ISNULL(@CreatedBy, NULL)) + '''
                    ,''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), GETDATE()) + '''
                    ,''' + NULL + '''    
                    ,''' + NULL + '''
                    )
        END'

            EXECUTE( @SQL ) 
END
```

Comment: What data types are CreatedBy and UpdatedBy in your EventDetail table?

Comment: They are GUID both of them

Comment: Please verify the last two columns in your `INSERT` statement.  You are concatenating NULL which will result in the entire SQL string being NULL (depending on the CONCAT_NULL_YEILDS_NULL setting).

Comment: thanks Paul that was it...this is my first posting... wow that was fast I hope to contribute myself in the future. thanks